# Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[Router]: after updating to Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I can't find the cause of error after upgrading Angular to version 5.0.1. Maybe someone has the same problem.

```
"dependencies": {  
    __"@angular/animations": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",__  
    __"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",__  
    __"@angular/common": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/compiler": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/core": "^5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/forms": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/http": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",__  
    __"@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/router": "~5.0.1"__  
}  

"devDependencies": {  
    __"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",__  
    __"@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.1",__  
    __"@angular/language-service": "~5.0.1"__  
}  


     const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'users',
            loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
        }
      ];

      export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);

    import { appRouting } from './app.routing';
        @NgModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            imports: [appRouting]
        ...
        )};
        ...
```

[image]

Comment: did you import `RouterModule` add the code to help more

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement might be wrong

Modify it as

```
import appRouting from './app.routing';
```

Alternatively, use `default`

```
export default appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modularized and nested xxxModule.ts make sure you are importing xxxModule.ts in your root **app.module.ts**
something like this...

 `imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        //
        // My components Imports...
        YTPModule,
        AMSModule,
        UQSModule,
        UMSModule,
        UPSModule,`

The same error drove me nuts as I was mechanically factoring out stuff from cluttered app.module.ts

I hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

seems like you created a separate module (Sub module) and forget to add something like below snippet.

```
@NgModule ({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot (appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```